# Two browser pages opened when using selenium on iframe on Streamlit

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, streamlit

I can't execute selenium code on the iframe page on streamlit. When I run the .py file by executing **streamlit run app5.py** on cmd, it generates two browsers with one being the streamlit app (localhost:8501) and the other one being an empty page with an alert message on the top saying "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software." My guess for the reason why selenium code is not running is because it's executing selenium on the empty page not on the streamlit page. Is there a way to remove or not populate the empty page?

Here's my code:

```
import streamlit as st
from dateutil.parser import parse
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

st.title("Auto Search App")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


components.iframe("https://wego.here.com/", height = 500)

search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search")))
search_input.click()
search_input.send_keys('Seattle')
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Here is the screenshot of the two pages (empty page is generated most recently) when I execute **streamlit run app5.py** on cmd:
[image: 1]

Comment: Selenium always runs new browser without `profile`, `cookies`, etc. and it doesn't use already opened browser. And `streamlit` always runs code with default browser and if it is already opened then it runs in this window. So both use different strategy to run browser and you get two windows. Maybe in selenium you should run `driver.get("http://localhost:8501")`

Comment: I'm not sure if both can run at the same time. Maybe `selenium` will have to run in separated thread. When I run code with `driver.get()` then it open many windows. It seems like steamlit runs code in some loop to update data periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Run selenium headless.

Code:

```
import streamlit as st
from dateutil.parser import parse
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

components.iframe("https://wego.here.com/", height = 500)

search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search")))
search_input.click()
search_input.send_keys('Seattle')
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using window_handles and switch_to_window method.

Before clicking the iframe first store the window handle

**See if it works**

```
import streamlit as st
from dateutil.parser import parse
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

st.title("Auto Search App")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

#Switch to the other window
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(window_before)

components.iframe("https://wego.here.com/", height = 500)

search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search")))
search_input.click()
search_input.send_keys('Seattle')
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```